# Typescript typing for function callback usable with a function declaration

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to type a callback function in Typescript that encodes the following 2 invariants in the type system:

1. if err == null then x is of type `T`
2. if err != null then x must not be referenced (`never`?)

```
type Callback<T> = {
  (error: null, value: T): void;
  (error: Error): void;
};

// The function that takes the typed callback.
function incrementAsync(x: number, cb: Callback<number>): void {
  if (x === 0) {
    return cb(new Error());
  }

  cb(null, x + 1); // should type-check
  cb(new Error()); // should type-check

  cb(new Error(), 1) // should fail type-check
  cb(null);          // should fail type-check
}
```

Here's the function signature that I really want:

```js
// Error: This overload signature is not compatible 
//        with its implementation signature.
function definedCb1(e: Error);
function definedCb1(e: null, x: number): void {}
incrementAsync(10, definedCb1); // error with strictNullChecks
```

Here's a looser function signature that type checks

```js
// BAD because types are too loose but this passes type-check.
function definedCb2(e: Error|null, x?: number): void {
  if (e === null) {
    // Is there a way to type this function, so the ! is not necessary?
    console.log(x! + 1);
    return;
  }
  // error because x might be undefined.
  console.log(x + 2);
}
incrementAsync(20, definedCb2) // Works
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20NOTE%3A%20enable%20options%20%3E%20strictNullChecks%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Callback%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20null%2C%20value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20Error)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20incrementAsync(x%3A%20number%2C%20cb%3A%20Callback%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(x%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20cb(new%20Error())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20cb(null%2C%20x%20%2B%201)%3B%20%2F%2F%20should%20type-check%0D%0A%20%20cb(new%20Error())%3B%20%2F%2F%20should%20type-check%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20cb(new%20Error()%2C%201)%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail%20type-check%0D%0A%20%20cb(null)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail%20type-check%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20How%20do%20you%20type%20the%20params%20of%20an%20arrow%20function%20to%20maintain%20the%20invariants%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%201.%20if%20err%20%3D%3D%20null%20then%20x%20is%20a%20number%0D%0A%2F%2F%202.%20if%20err%20!%3D%20null%20then%20x%20must%20not%20be%20referenced%20(never%3F)%0D%0Aconst%20arrowCb%3A%20Callback%3CNumber%3E%20%3D%20(err%2C%20x)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(err%20!%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22error%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20console.log(x%20%2B%201)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AincrementAsync(10%2C%20arrowCb)%3B%20%2F%2F%20GOOD%20type-checks%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20BAD%20because%20errors%20with%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20overload%20signature%20is%20not%20compatible%20with%20its%20implementation%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20signature.%0D%0Afunction%20definedCb1(e%3A%20Error)%3B%0D%0Afunction%20definedCb1(e%3A%20null%2C%20x%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0D%0AincrementAsync(10%2C%20definedCb1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20with%20strictNullChecks%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20BAD%20because%20types%20are%20too%20loose%20but%20this%20passes%20type-check.%0D%0Afunction%20definedCb2(e%3A%20Error%7Cnull%2C%20x%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(e%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20type%20this%20function%2C%20so%20the%20!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20is%20not%20necessary%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x!%20%2B%201)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20error%20because%20x%20might%20be%20undefined.%0D%0A%20%20console.log(x%20%2B%202)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AincrementAsync(20%2C%20definedCb2)%20%2F%2F%20Works) enable `strictNullChecks` and `noImplicitAny`.

Comment: `function logNum(error: Error | null, x?: number): void {` ...

Comment: and change `if (error == null)` by `if (error !== null)` if i understand what you want to do

Comment: I edited the question for added detail: Is there a way to add types to a function so that either: 1. err == null and `x` has type `T` or 2. err != null and `x` must not be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on `strictNullChecks`, then this meets your requirements.

```
interface Callback<T> {
  (error: Error): void;
  (error: null, value: T): void;
}

function incrementAsync(x: number, cb: Callback<number>): void {
  cb(new Error());          // works
  cb(null, x + 1);          // works

  cb(null);                 // error
  cb(new Error(), 'foo');   // error
  cb(null, 'foo');          // error
  cb(new Error(), 10);      // error    
}
```

Here it is [in the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Callback%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20Error)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20null%2C%20value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20incrementAsync(x%3A%20number%2C%20cb%3A%20Callback%3Cnumber%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20cb(new%20Error())%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0A%20%20cb(null%2C%20x%20%2B%201)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20cb(null)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%20%20cb(new%20Error()%2C%20'foo')%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%20%20cb(null%2C%20'foo')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%20%20cb(new%20Error()%2C%2010)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

The `strictNullChecks` flag prevents all types from [being nullable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types).

Comment: Right, but I'd like to encode the invariant that if error == null, then value is T into the type system.  The simpler Callback is too loose.

Comment: The simple callback has that invariant already, because `value` must be `T` whether `error` is null or not. I have added use cases to my answer, and am interested to hear other ones that you might have.

Comment: In the simple callback,the value with type T is optional.  I'd like to enforce that the value is T and is present if error == null.  So, `cb(new Error(), 10);` should error and so should `cb(null);`

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  Your approach works for type-checking inside the function that calls the callback.  My difficulty is creating a function that matches the same type-level invariants as `Callback<T>`. I've added more detail to the original question to show the difficulty.